# Take canvas @ViewChild that has *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, chart.js, viewchild

I've seen the majority related posts in here but nothing seems to work at all, as whatever I do I always get "undefined" when I console.log my element with ViewChild or "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined".

What I am trying to do is to get the canvas element from HTML in Typescript with viewChild and on the Canvas, I have as well a *ngIf directive. And in the end, what I would like to do is to set that background colour of my graph to be gradient.

Here is what I've tried to do so far but no success. If you guys have any idea I would really appreciate it.

HTML

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row class="ion-padding">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-spinner *ngIf="graphLoading"></ion-spinner>
      <ion-text
        *ngIf="!graphLoading && (bioValueData.length === 0 || timePeriodLabels.length ===0)"
        >No data available for the selected period
      </ion-text>
      <canvas
        #bioGraph
        *ngIf="!graphLoading && bioValueData.length !== 0 && timePeriodLabels.length !== 0"
        baseChart
        [datasets]="biomarkerValueData"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
        [labels]="timePeriodLabels"
        [colors]="chartColors"
      ></canvas>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

TS

```
 private bioGraph: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild("bioGraph", { static: false }) set content(
    content: ElementRef
  ) {
    if (content) {
      this.bioGraph = content;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.bioGraph);
    const ctx = (<HTMLCanvasElement>(
      this.bioGraph.nativeElement
    )).getContext("2d");

    const gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
    gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0.6)");
    gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(244, 144, 128, 0.6)");
    this.chartColors = [
      {
        backgroundColor: gradientFill,
      },
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Change the *ngIf= to [hidden]=

Comment: You should not use "*ngIf" with ViewChild, try [hidden]. With "hidden" element is in the DOM but just not visible.

Comment: Hi! Thank you answers! Is there any other way apart from [hidden] I am asking because if I am using this it breaks another part of my app?

Comment: Have you tried to set static:true?

Comment: yes, but no change. Also, I get now this error when using [hidden] "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'."